# Converting Parse Relation to list in adapter class

Tags: android, android-adapter, parse-server

I would like a populate a TextView in one of my fragments with a list of users who are attending a specific trip. On the Parse server, Trip contains a Parse Relation of users attending each instance of a Trip. The following method is in my Trip model class to retrieve a String list of the users' names.

```
 public List<String> getMemberNames(){
    final List members = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        ParseRelation<ParseUser> relation = getRelation(KEY_USER);
        ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
                for (ParseUser parseUser : parseUsers)
                {
                    members.add(parseUser.getUsername());
                }
                Log.d("relation", members.toString());
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return members;
}
```

In my adapter, I call this with the line:

```
 viewHolder.tvMembers.setText(Arrays.toString(trip.getMemberNames().toArray()));
```

However, when I run the debugger, the list of members remains empty. Any advice on why this is? Is is not possible to query in the Trip model? I appreciate the help!

Comment: That query is _asynchronous_. It will not have completed by the time you return from the `getMemberNames()` method.

Comment: Thank you! What is the best way to deal with this? Should I move this method to the fragment and call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after adding a member to the List?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like it'd work for your setup.